# Should I buy server or build it?

Tags: windows, small-business, hardware

I need a server for a small company with about 20 people. The server will be used as a fileserver for many MS Office files simultaneously. I tried to look at complete servers but I don't like any of the ones I've looked at. They require you to buy HDDs and an OS, which adds about 300 (currency unknown) more than I want to pay.

The server is for Windows but i already own a license and have a CD.

Is there real economy if I build it and can someone estimate what hardware I need for this kind of server?

Comment: As Hyppy says, consider a NAS. But in any case, the answer to this question is almost always "Buy - unless you've got a very specialised requirement and (with all due respect) you don't have to ask others what hardware you need". It's simply not worth the extra cost of support on a self build. There are plenty of vendors out there that will sell you a "bare metal" server with no OS licence, Dell for example, will do so quite happily. I've *never* purchased a server with an OS on it from Dell, and I've purchased a lot of servers.

Answer (score 5):

File server? That's it? Buy a NAS.

[NewEgg NAS Store](http://www.newegg.com/Store/SubCategory.aspx?SubCategory=124)

Comment: Is there way to work simultaneously with excel spreadsheet in NAS as if you share it with windows?

Answer (score 2):

For such things people usually use MS SharePoint Server. If you have licensed Windows 2008 Server OS 64-bit you can install MS SharePoint 2010 Foundation and use it for document collaboration. Consider buying small barebone server and adding hardware (HDD, Memory) as load on server demands